# Mathematical Statistics: A random 4-tuple of digits has 3 as its smallest digit.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $X=\{0,1,...,9\}$.  A random 4-tuple, $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ is selected from $X^4$.  I am calculating the probability that the least digit is 3.

My attempted solution is:  We need to select 3 and then three other digits larger than 3, which if they occur in that order, have probability

$$\frac{1}{10}\cdot\left(\frac{6}{10}\right)^3$$

However, since these digits may occur in any order, we should multiply by $4!$ in order to count all rearrangements.

Something about this seems too easy though--is this solution valid?  If I were to calculate the probability that the 2nd largest digit is 3, would it have solution

$$\frac{1}{10}\cdot \frac{3}{10}\cdot\left(\frac{6}{10}\right)^2\cdot 4!$$

Comment: $\frac{1}{10}\cdot\left(\frac{6}{10}\right)^3$ counts the number of sequences with $3$ as the first number and the others greater than $3$.  There are only $4$, not $4!$ ways to reorder this because you just need to choose the position of the $3$.  You already counted $3456$ and $3654$ before counting the reorderings.  You also have not counted sequences with more than one $3$.  Daniel Ordoñez has shown a good way to count the cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you have four types of favorable cases (according to the number of 3's in the vector) Favorable cases: $\binom{4}{1}6^3+\binom{4}{2}6^2+\binom{4}{3}6+\binom{4}{4}$

The total number of cases are $10^4$.

By making the divison you get a probability of approximately $0.1684$